# UITableView indexPath section logic

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

This is the abridged code for my cellForRowAtIndexPath UITableView delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"blahblahblah"];
if (cell == nil) {
    // No cell to reuse => create a new one
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"blahblahblah"] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = @"";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
cell.backgroundView = NULL; //problem here

// Initialize cell
//blah blah blah
//now to the good part...

if(indexPath.section == 1) {
    cell.backgroundView = deleteButton;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.textLabel.text = nil;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
}

else if(indexPath.section == 0) {
    NSLog(@"section: %i row: %i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"foobar";
            //more stuff
            break;

        //lots more cases

        default:
            break;
    }
}

return cell;
```

}

My problem is that the first cell in section 1 (section 0 has 10 cells, section 1 has only 1 cell) is getting assigned the information that is only supposed to be assigned to cell 0 of the first section. So, instead of getting the deleteButton background and etc, it gets the label title "foobar". I'm not really sure why this is happening, because my if statements are pretty clear. Any ideas?

Edit: setting the backgroundView to NULL causes those cells with text to, when they leave the view, come back without any background. So that isn't a viable solution. Also, the text for the detailTextLabel is still set on the cell that shouldn't have any text.

This is how it looks, with the cell backgroundViews set to nil and the text showing up on the delete cell where it shouldn't:

[image]

**Solution, as recommended by Alex Deem (replacing old dequeue code with this code):**

```
NSString* identifier;
if(indexPath.section == 0)
    identifier = @"0";
else
    identifier = @"1";
UISwitch *switchView;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    // No cell to reuse => create a new one
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the documentation regarding the reuse of cells.

You should be using a different reuseIdentifier for each of the two sections, since they are fundamentally differently styled cells.

Comment: Ah, yes, that did it. Updated the question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

add a closing `}` bracket to these lines of code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"blahblahblah"];
if (cell == nil) {
    // No cell to reuse => create a new one
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"blahblahblah"] autorelease];
}
....
....
....
if(indexPath.section == 1) {
   ....
   ....
}
if(indexPath.section == 0) {
   ....
   ....
}
```

and I suspect you will have better results in your table.

The way things are working right now (at least as far as I can tell in your code), you create one cell and it gets initialized to something.  It never gets reset to the values & data of anything else that's being requested.

Comment: That didn't do it- now both cells at row 0 in their sections get *both* the text from the cell in section 0 and the background from the cell in section 1. But what did it, as I discovered on accident, is using different identifiers for dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier and reuseIndentifier... Is this a bad practice?

Comment: update your original question with your new code... and yes, the identifiers should be the same within a single table view.

Comment: Right before you do your `if (indexPath.section == 1)` thing, do `cell.textLabel.text = @"";` and `cell.backgroundView = NULL;`.  That should fix the last two issues.  Oh, and do you really have an `else` before the `if` there with no `if / then` pair above it?

Comment: what does `PROBLEM HERE` mean and what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is structured wrong.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"blahblahblah"];
if (cell == nil)
```

dqueueReuseableCellWithIdentifier will return an existing previously created cell if it is no longer in use.  `If cell == nil` you should create a new cell and set defaults common to all cells.  However any setting of data unique to that indexPath should be done after the

```
if(cell==nil) block.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"blahblahblah"];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1         reuseIdentifier:@"blahblahblah"] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text=@"unique text";
return cell;
```

Comment: Please see the comment I posted on Micheal Dautermann's answer.